# Como fazer a chamada do Teclado Horizontal ao clicar no EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, teclado

## Explicação:

Eu tenho uma aplicação que possui um campo do tipo `EditText` usado para observação, do qual é pequeno demais, pois não há espaço para ele.

Se eu abro a tela no modo "orientação horizontal" e clico no campo, o Android se encarrega de abrir um o teclado horizontal do qual tem espaço para digitar e um botão "concluir", como podemos ver na imagem abaixo:

[image: campo automatico android]

Eu gostaria que ele ativasse esta funcionalidade do Android sempre. Teoricamente ela só é acionada se a orientação está "deitada" ou seja, no modo horizontal.

## Pergunta:

Quero saber como fazer pra ativar o Teclado Horizontal independente da orientação que o usuário estiver, como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 1):

Poderia mostrar o XML do EditText que você está utilizando?
No meu caso, o teclado sempre funciona para ambas as orientações. Segue exemplo.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg_selector"
    android:hint="@string/user_name_hint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="@integer/user_name_max_length"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/user_name_max_width"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/user_password"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/user_name_text_size"
    app:colorHint="@android:color/black"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho o mesmo problema seu, porem a necessidade é invertida, pois no meu caso eu sempre queria abrir o teclado da orientação portrait (vertical).
Pelas pesquisa que fiz não como mudar essa configuração pelo seu app, pois esse layout é do teclado que você está utilizando. 
Para resolver isso você tem que instalar um novo modelo de teclado ou desenvolver um para as suas necessidades.

[Segue a documentação para você criar um Custom Keyboard no Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)

Comment: Não deu certo aqui, tentei tudo oque diz aí no link, mas parece que não é mais feito dessa forma, quem sabe isto esteja depreciado, não sei.... mas não consigo implementar.